# Load GLTF/GLB Model into NextJS App via HTML input tag with React Three Fiber

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, next.js, react-three-fiber

I want to provide HTML input to upload own 3d model using GLTF/GLB format from local using React three fiber, react three drei, and three-stdlib within NextJs App, but I received error with the message is

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> TypeError: url.lastIndexOf is not a function

The following is my snippet code, I still don't know which line of code caused error

1. HTML input for upload

```js
if (e.target.files[0].name?.includes('glb') || e.target.files[0].name?.includes('gltf')) {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
    reader.onload = (_url) => {
      setThreeDUrl(_url)
      setThreeDFile(e.target.files[0])
      setShowAudioThumbnailModal(true)
    }
}
return(
  <Canvas>
    <Model1 threeDUrl={threeDUrl} threeDFile={threeDFile} />
  </Canvas>
)
```

2. 3D Component

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three-stdlib'
import { OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'

const ThreeDModel2 = ({ threeDUrl }) => {
    const loadedGltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, threeDUrl)

    return (
        <>
            <primitive object={loadedGltf.scene}></primitive>
            <OrbitControls />
            <ambientLight />
        </>
    )
}

export default ThreeDModel2
```

Is there any suggestion to solve this problem? is my code still haven't worked fine yet? Your help is very thankful for me

Comment: Can you show us the full error stack trace? It's not clear where the error originates from.